# Invalid background modes error message when submitting to the App Store

Tags: app-store, core-location

I have an issue with submitting my app to the app store. My app wants to run in the background, so I have set "App registers for location updates in required back ground modes" array in the plist. When I try to upload to the app store, I am getting the following error message:

> Invalid UIBackgroundModes: the UIBackgroundmodes key contains an invalid value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should open your apps info.plist in Text Edit, find the background modes section and see if there is anything strange or off about it. If you can't figure it out from there just post the contents of the plist in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, below shown is what i added to my plist. please have a look int it.     <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
 <string>location</string>
    </array>

Answer (score 4):

sorry i can not comment so i want to clear my query on this.

My app need to work in background mode for push notification & location.

I am facing same issue & i am unable to get what is wrong in this.

[image]

Thanks

Updated:
I then found that Removing the "Location" attribute which was added  manually which was not required once added in capabilities section. (for new versions of Xcode the provision is given in capabilities section under background mode to configure that your app is using background mode for location, push notification etc.)

Answer (score 4):

I also got the similar issue when i copied the background mode from other target's plist.

I follow the below steps to fix it

info.plist > open as > source code

[image]

Then search for UIBackgroundModes.
What i see is wrong is :

[image]

To fix this i have change the **UIBackgroundModes** to :

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

**There is other convenient way of doing it is**

**Just turn off the the background mode from "Signing and capabilities" and on it again your plist will update automatic.**

hope it will help to others who are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check "Required background modes" on info.plist, I had an empty `<string></string>` there, after I deleted it the problem was solved!

[info.plist image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0gJf.png)